# Mysql compare data with android data

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

How can i get android to take a mysql table's values and compare it to itself?

So far i have a table called versioncode with the value of 1.0.2
How do i get my .php file to pull up this information and then transfer it into android so android can compare the versioncode 1.0.2 to the version name i t has right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that information straight from the database with Java's DB adapter, or call on the .PHP script to do that.
Then you compare it to the version variable in the variables file. If it is not equal, you show a message that urges the user to upgrade.